# Json array size stuck to 10

Tags: android, json, parsing, google-books

I'm trying to parse the items (the books) of the Google Books API using Gson, but for some reason, the JsonArray size is stuck to 10 if I try to access an index greater than that it will crash, but there should be 10000+ objects in the array. I tried to parse it with the JSON library from the android studio but I had the exact same error.

```
public String parse(String jsonLine) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonLine);

    System.out.println("jelement " + jelement.toString());
    System.out.println("Number of objects " + jelement.getAsJsonObject().get("totalItems"));
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println("jobject " + jobject.toString());
    JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("items");
    jobject = jarray.get(500).getAsJsonObject();
```

And the error:

> Number of objects 10275
>
> **FATAL EXCEPTION**: main Process:
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:  Invalid index 500, size is 10

Comment: can you show us the response jsonLine?

Comment: Because items jsonArray have only 10 object while you get value of index 500.

Comment: You are printing totalItems then accessing items - why do you think those should be the same?

Comment: please show your response jsonline.

Comment: Have you check, the size of "jarray" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this API is paginated API which means, for example, let's say you are making a call for Google Books API.

Now there may be thousands/millions of books. But for the efficient implementation of the API, they might send only first 10 books,

Example:
API call: **http://www.somewebsite.com/api/books**
The result will be a result of 10 books. But the JSON has total Books count. So using this you can access the paginated API

```
{
  totalBooks: 100,
  books: [
    {
      //Book1
    },
    {
      //Book2
    }
  ]
}
```

So now there are 100 books but still, you receive only 10 books. 
So to access 55th book, you might have to make a request like
API: **http://www.somewebsite.com/api/books/5**

Response to this API call will have books from 51 to 60.

```
{
  totalBooks: 100,
  books: [
    {
      //Book51
    },
    {
      //Book52
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i think that's the reason, I'll test and come back with the results thanks